# Laravel 5.5 Checking if the data is on the database

Tags: php, laravel

Anyone can help me. I am new in laravel development.

```
table name
*Masterlist
*Users
```

column names

```
Masterlist = [id,name,date_of_birth,course];
Users = [id,name,date_of_birth,course];
```

I am working in `RegisterController.php`

The flow of this is..

User registration needs to check on masterlist data's the `name,date_of_birth,course`

If the user registration is equal to the data of the masterlist data's
the registration will success then the data will save to the user table.

Thank you for help.

Comment: can't you use [`exists()` in validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-exists)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume Your `MasterList` is model of table `MasterList`. Then you can first check your `masterList` that your data exists or not, if exists then do your `user registration` like the following-

```
$masterList = MasterList::where('name',$name)->where('date_of_birth',$date_of_birth)->where('course',$course)->first();
 if($masterList!=null){
     ///Your user registration process
 }
```

And if you are having your data from `$request` object then-

```
$masterList = MasterList::where('name',$request->input('name'))->where('date_of_birth',$request->input('date_of_birth'))->where('course',$request->input('course'))->first();
 if($masterList!=null){
     ///Your user registration process
 }
```

To `redirect` with `error message` you could do something like the below after the if statement-

```
return redirect()->back()->with([
                'error' => 'Sorry! You are not listed in MasterList!!',
            ])->withInput();
```

Comment: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth\MasterList' not found i get this error.

Comment: Change it with your own MasterList model class

Comment: Its okay now the first part. Thank you :) I working now in the displaying error . If the user didnt match the data in masterlist . How can i do that?

Comment: @MiksAlibo I have updated my answer, have a look now for displaying error

Answer (score 1):

Override the `register` method in `RegisterController` as follow:

```
    public function register(Request $request)
{
    $this->validator($request->all())->validate();

    //query the Masterlist table
    $masterList = Masterlist::where('name', $request->input('name'))
        ->where('date_of_birth', $request->input('date_of_birth'))
        ->where('course', $request->input('course'))
        ->value('id');

    if ($masterList) {
        //masterList exist -> proceed registration process
        event(new Registered($user = $this->create($request->all())));

        $this->guard()->login($user);

        return $this->registered($request, $user)
            ?: redirect($this->redirectPath());
    }
    else {
        //masterList not exist => process the error;
    }
}
```

**Note:** `register` function originally defined in `RegistersUsers` trait which is used in `RegisterController`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i cant do override the register because im still new in laravel.  I need only the basic way on how to fix my problem.

Comment: No problem. To override register method: copy the register function from the answer, then paste it in App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController.

Answer (score 0):

Create a validator in your controller.

`$validator = Validator::make()`

create a customize rule.

`php artisan make:rule filePath`

Send the MasterList and Users data to your rule(when create the rule instance),Finally,Compare the data in you rule ,Return true or false.
I suggest you use validator and rule.it useful and convenient.